# No puedo borrar mi usuario de Git

Tags: git, github, control-de-versiones

Estoy teniendo problemas para cambiar mi usuario de `git`. Anteriormente tenía un usuario, ahora necesito cambiarlo por cuestiones de trabajo. **El problema es que al momento de cambiarlo, no lo hace.**

Ya intente con:

`$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`

Pero cuando ejecuto el comando para ver el usuario me sale el anterior.

También borre credenciales genéricas de `github` y sigo sin poder cambiar de usuario.

¿Alguna solución que conozcan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para cambiar en Git el usuario y el nombre de forma global necesitas ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

- Para el nombre: `git config [--global] user.name "Nombre completo"`
- Para el email: `git config [--global] user.email "johndoe@example.com"`

Además necesitas también **cambiar tus credenciales**, por lo que despues de estos comandos, debes ejeuctar:

`git config --global credential.username "Nuevo_usuario"`

### Bonus 1

Puedes ver el nombre y el email de cualquier repositorio local con el siguiente comando:

`git config --list`

### Bonus 2

Incluso si usas `--local` puedes usar diferentes credenciales en cada repositorio.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema puede ser que le falte espacios

Mal:
`global user.emai"tu_email"`

Bien:
`global user.emai "tu_email"`